# How to Show Cluster Colour on xgb.plot.importance?

Tags: r, rstudio, xgboost

I am trying to plot the relative importance from my XGBoost result. However, my result plot does not show the cluster/cluster colour of each variable. How can I make the culster colour show up in the plot?

```
mat <- xgb.importance(feature_names = colnames(training_set), model = xgb1)
xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix = mat[1:20], xlab = "Relative importance")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for to use ggplot's back-end, which you can do with `xgb.ggplot.importance`. You can find a reproducible example [here.](https://rdrr.io/cran/xgboost/man/xgb.plot.importance.html) Specifically:

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(xgboost)

data(agaricus.train)

bst <- xgboost(data = agaricus.train$data, label = agaricus.train$label, 
               max_depth = 3,
               eta = 1, nthread = 2, nrounds = 2, objective = 
               "binary:logistic")

importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(colnames(agaricus.train$data), model = 
 bst)

xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix, rel_to_first = TRUE, xlab = "Relative 
importance")

#Here the use ggplot
gg <- xgb.ggplot.importance(importance_matrix, measure = "Frequency", 
                            rel_to_first = TRUE)
gg + ggplot2::ylab("Frequency")
```

Your code may look something like below:

```
gg <- xgb.ggplot.importance(mat[1:20], xlab = "Relative importance",
                            rel_to_first = TRUE)

gg + ggplot2::ylab("Relative importance")
```